# Is Zalama stronger than Zeno?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

Considering that the Super Shenron's, who is summoned forth by collecting all the 7 Super Dragon Balls, wish-granting power was able to reverse the erasure of 7 universes, does that mean that he is stronger? Also, since Super Shenron can reverse Zeno's, possibly strongest, skill, does that mean someone can wish him away through Super Shenron?

Comment: Not having seen the show I don't entirely understand the question, but I do know that "which is stronger/which would win" questions are almost always closed as primarily opinion based. Do you have an objective metric to measure which is stronger or is this just theorizing? If the latter, this will have to be closed as opinion based.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe the objective metric can be found on these three pages: https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Zeno, https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Zalama, and https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Super_Shenron. Read their pages, specifically the section under the subheading "power."

Comment: Probably not, as the recreation of those universes was in line with Zeno's will. He was not opposing the dragon, and may have been helping. Furthermore, the dragon has severe limits on when he acts- if Zeno chose, he could just destroy those universes again and that would be it.